# Is there a solution to log all messages in rabbitmq but don't using rabbitmq_management?

Tags: rabbitmq

I do know [rabbitmq_tracing](http://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html), which is a plugin of RabbitMQ, can provides a GUI to capture traced messages and log them in text or JSON format files. But the plugin is performance costing, is there a way to log all messages without this plugin?
Or is there a eclectic way to log messages automatically without using the [management plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html)? Because configuring traces on the GUI is not tolerant for some customers.
Any response would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the actual log messages, or (AMQP) messages that go through exchanges?

Comment: I mean all the messages going through the exchanges and queues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a good solution to log all messages without `rabbitmq_management`. But with this plugin turned on, add and delete rabbitmq trace via command line:

Add a new trace:
[windows:] `curl -i -u guest:guest -H "content-type:application/json" -XPUT ^ http://localhost:15672/api/traces/%2f/my-trace ^ -d"{""format"":""json"",""pattern"":""#"",""max_payload_bytes"":1000}"`
[linux:] `curl -i -u guest:guest -H "content-type:application/json" -XPUT \ http://localhost:15672/api/traces/%2f/my-trace \ -d'{"format":"text","pattern":"#", "max_payload_bytes":1000}'`

Delete a trace:
[windows:] `curl -i -u guest:guest -H "content-type:application/json" -XDELETE ^ http://localhost:15672/api/traces/%2f/my-trace`
[linux:] `curl -i -u guest:guest -H "content-type:application/json" -XDELETE \ http://localhost:15672/api/traces/%2f/my-trace`